# Is it possible to access the user's filesystem and perform CRUD operations on his filesystem using django or node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django, web-development-server

I want to access the filesystem of the client , and delete some files from his system. is it possible for me to make any website which can perform such task? if yes using what we can perform these? Django?Node.js? or anything else? if not can i perform the same using any other method? like API etc?
thanks in advance.

Comment: "is it possible for me to make any website which can perform such task?" . No. Web applications (whether via client-side JavaScript or server-side code) do not have access to the filesystem of the device where the browser is running (apart from limited exceptions where the user explicitly grants access, such as choosing a file to upload). Can you imagine the fun that hackers and thieves would have if you could easily access the filesystem? Even if you had to ask for consent, many users would grant it without really realising the implications. So for that reason it's completely prevented.

Comment: What exactly did you want to achieve by doing this anyway? The files that the user has on their system are no business of yours. Why does your application care if they are deleted or not? If you want to give the user a tool to manage some files, you'd have to write a desktop application which the user must download and execute themselves. It's the user's choice how they manage their files, not your web application's.